# Math.floor в массиве

Tags: javascript

```js
let styles = ["Джаз", "Блюз"];
styles.push("Рок-н-ролл");
styles[Math.floor((styles.length - 1) / 2)] = "Классика"; // Что делает это строка? Можно пожалуйста                                                         
                                                         //  объяснить подробнее.
alert( styles.shift() );
styles.unshift("Рэп", "Регги");

alert(styles);
```

Answer (score 2):

Эта строка обращается к (присваивает значение) элементу в середине массива (нечетное количество элементов) или элементу перед серединой массива (четное количество элементов).

```js
console.log(Math.floor((5 - 1) / 2));
console.log(Math.floor((6 - 1) / 2));
```

Comment: styles[Math.floor((styles.length - 1) / 2)]  это от текущей длины массива 3 элемента, отнять один элемент, а потом разделить на 2, затем округлить в меньшую сторону?
Как я понимаю значение после всех этих операций будет равно 1 или что?

Comment: @Человек Сколько нужно времени, чтобы это проверить?