# Ошибка (42, 45): Expecting ')'

Tags: kotlin

Недавно стал изучать kotlin, создал кнопку

при которой
пользователь
переходит на второй экран,

но тут я столкнулся с непонятной ошибкой **(42, 45): Expecting ')'** в файле MainActivity.kt

****Файл MainActivity.kt (главный экран)****

```
    package com.example.myapplication

    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.Toast
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun SecondScreen(view: View) {             ***//Функция перехода на второй экран***
    val randomIntent = Intent(packageContext: this, SecondActivity2::class.java)
    startActivity(randomIntent)
    }
    }
```

**Файл activity_main.xml (главный экран)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <Button
   android:id="@+id/middle"
   android:layout_width="125dp"
   android:layout_height="45dp"
   android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
   android:onClick="SecondScreen"         ***// Событие перехода***
   android:text="Random"
   app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/left"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.
```

**Файл SecondActivity2.kt (второй экран)**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class SecondActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Укажите комментом, на какой именно строке ошибка

Comment: У вас так и есть в коде `***//Функция перехода на второй экран***`? Если что, первые три звездочки не являются частью комментария.

Comment: Нету это я тут написал, чтобы вы долго не искали

Comment: Ошибка, где функция перехода   val randomIntent = Intent(packageContext: this, SecondActivity2::class.java)

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171654/math-floor-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я  не знаю языка, но эта ошибка означает, что функция `Intent`  не ожидает ещё одного параметра после запятой (45 позиция), а хочет уже закрыть скобку.

Вот это `packageContext: this` что означает? В [примере](https://www.fandroid.info/urok-5-kotlin-dobavlenie-vtorogo-ekrana-v-android-prilozhenie/2/) я вижу просто `this` - **объект**, а синтаксис `packageContext: this` означает ведь указание **типа** после двоеточия.

Не так ли нужно ?

```
val randomIntent = Intent(this, SecondActivity2::class.java)
```

Comment: Я понял в чем проблема, благодаря вам. Спасибо. Вы знаете java(android)?

Comment: Вы смогли найти ошибку благодаря знаниям java(android) ?

Comment: @Человек Он смог найти ошибку благодаря здравому смыслу и знанию базовых вещей, которые применимы к любому языку.

Comment: `Intent(packageContext: this,` - очередной случай копирования кода с видео из интернета. Здесь `packageContext:` - это не часть кода, а подсказка IDE.